# Drupal 8 JavaScript and Best Practice

Tags: theming, javascript, 8

I am building a theme for Drupal 8 that I want to make available in the drupal.org theme section. As such, I want it to conform to best practice code wise. When adding JavaScript, I notice there has been some changes. Here is how I do it:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page (&$vars, $hook) {
  $path = drupal_get_path ('theme', 'THEMENAME');
  // Render the main scripts file.
  $local_js = array (
    '#attached' => array (
      'js' => array (
        $path . '/js/THEMENAME.js' => array ('group' => JS_THEME, 'weight' => 9999),
        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js' => array ('group' => JS_THEME, 'weight' => 9000),
      ),
    ),
  );
  drupal_render ($local_js);
}
```

Is this it? the best-practice way?

Edit:

In accordance to Aneek's answer I am now including JavaScript this way:

First, I created a THEMENAME.libraries.yml:

```
THEMENAME-base:
  version: 1.0
  js:
    //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js: {}
    js/THEMENAME.js: {}
```

Then, in THEMENAME.info.yml I added the libraries:

```
--snip--
core: 8.x
stylesheets:
  all:
    - css/grid.css
    - css/style.css
regions:
  header: 'Header image'
  home_intro: 'Home intro'
  breadcrumbs: Breadcrumbs
  content: Content
  sidebar-main: 'Sidebar main'
libraries:
  - THEMENAME/THEMENAME-base
```

This method includes the JavaScript files to all pages on the site. If one needs to include on specific pages only, the preprocess_page would probably be the way to do it.

Comment: Btw. You should use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` instead of deprecated `drupal_render()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the best available themes like Adaptivetheme or Omega, they followed the yml structure and placed the JavaScript files in **"omega.libraries.yml"** file.

If you are using template.php then for preprocess HOOKs I think they have implemented a file with .theme extension instead of template.php. See https://www.drupal.org/node/1967614

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into those themes. the THEMENAME.libraries.yml sounds like the right way to go. Not sure if that is the best-practice way thought?

Comment: Welcome.
Have a look at the URLs,
https://www.drupal.org/node/2228783 - Remove 'scripts' and add 'libraries' key to theme info files.
https://www.drupal.org/node/2201089 - hook_library_info() is replaced by *.libraries.yml file
https://www.drupal.org/node/1764252 - Generalize the use of library declaration for core JavaScript.

Comment: Documentation on how to achive this was recently added to drupal.org: See https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/adding-javascript

Comment: Also, there is this blog-post from x-team describing in detail this aspect here: http://x-team.com/2015/04/deep-dive-anatomy-drupal-8-theming/

Answer (score 1):

As of newer versions of Drupal 8, the "js"-key (or "css") is not allowed anymore in the #attached-array. Use "libraries" instead.